# PHP Multidimensional Associative Array to JS Object Using json_encode()

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array, json

I am perplexed and cannot figure out why this JSON object code is not coming out like I think it should.

For reasons not important to theis example, the PHP array is created from another array. As a PHP array, this works fine.

```
for($i=0;$i<$FileCount;$i++)
{
    $FileList[$i] = array
    (
        "Category" => $Category, "FileName" => $FileName, "Ext" => $Ext, "Title" => $Title, "ShortName" => $ShortName
    );
}

print_r($FileList);
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Category] => AntiqueGlass [FileName] => AntiqueGlass-BlackGlassBox-B [Ext] => jpg [Title] => BlackGlassBox [ShortName] => AntiqueGlass-BlackGlassBox ) [1] => Array ( [Category] => AntiqueGlass [FileName] => AntiqueGlass-BluePicture-B [Ext] => jpg [Title] => BluePicture [ShortName] => AntiqueGlass-BluePicture ) )
```

I then do this, with the result of the write shown underneath

```
$json_array=json_encode($FileList);
echo('
<script type="text/javascript">
    var JSFileList = '.json_encode($json_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT).';
    document.write(JSFileList);
</script>'."\n");

[{"Category":"AntiqueGlass","FileName":"AntiqueGlass-BlackGlassBox-B","Ext":"jpg","Title":"BlackGlassBox","ShortName":"AntiqueGlass-BlackGlassBox"},{"Category":"AntiqueGlass","FileName":"AntiqueGlass-BluePicture-B","Ext":"jpg","Title":"BluePicture","ShortName":"AntiqueGlass-BluePicture"}]
```

I believe the result should come out something like this

```
{"0":("Category":"AntiqueGlass","FileName":"AntiqueGlass-BlackGlassBox-B","Ext":"jpg","Title":"BlackGlassBox","ShortName":"AntiqueGlass-BlackGlassBox")},{"1":("Category":"AntiqueGlass","FileName":"AntiqueGlass-BluePicture-B","Ext":"jpg","Title":"BluePicture","ShortName":"AntiqueGlass-BluePicture")}
```

The intent is to access the object like this

```
JSFileList[i].FileName
```

All my research says this should work. I am at a loss to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why use force object? What you ant in JavaScript is an array of objects. Just plain old json_encode will be fine if you only call it once.

Comment: It's really unnecessary, as json_encode will force it anyway, because it is, at lease partly, an associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `json_encode` twice:

```
$json_array=json_encode($FileList);
//.....
json_encode($json_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

you must use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`-option in the first call, after that `$json_array` already is a String,  JSON_FORCE_OBJECT will have no effect there.

Of course the resulting variable `JSFileList` with the double-encoding  will also be a string, when you need to access the object in JS encode it only 1 time(`document.write` then would print something like `[object Object]`).

Comment: As did I, obviously (grin). Got lost somewhere in my experimenting ... And that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{...},{...},{...}]
```

This is an array of objects. You can access the individual objects by the numeric array index, like `JSFileList[2].FileName`. It already works as you need it.

Javascript distinguishes between continuously numerically indexed arrays (`[]`) and associative objects (`{}`), PHP does not. `json_encode` encodes all continuously numerically indexed PHP arrays to Javascript arrays, anything else to objects.

Comment: The result of JSFileList[0].FileName is [. The result of JSFileList[1].FileName is (. The result of JSFileList[2].FileName is ".

Comment: CORRECTION: The result of JSFileList[0].FileName is undefined. The result of JSFileList[0] is [ . The result of JSFileList[1] is (, etc.

Comment: Actually yes, because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/21521138/476. Combine that and my answer.